# Removing uneeded dictionary variables when using the Start 2010 workflow Action

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a 2013 workflow that starts a number of 2010 workflows.  I am converting these over to the new HTTP calls, but I'm running into a problem.  It seems when you use the "Start 2010 Workflow" it creates a dictionary variable for that action.  I need to know if there is a way to delete those unneeded dictionary variables.  They are not in the local variable list so I cannot delete that way.  I need to delete them as they are pushing my variable count over 50 and I cannot publish the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

So Microsoft in its great wisdom decided that they were not going to give the user a way to delete the variables that are created when you use the "Start 2010 Workflow".  I have to say, they are geniuses at Microsoft to not give the user a way to delete variables that are no longer needed.  Here is a round about way of doing though if you need to do it.  Scroll down and the answer will be there.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/e9d7b2ba-593d-4524-93ee-a76a579fc6ff/deleting-coordination-action-output-variables-in-spd-2013?forum=sharepointcustomization